# Why am I getting this "called to member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object" error?

Tags: php, mysql

Why is this code not working? I'm met with the "called to member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object" error when PHP gets to this point.

```
                $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    print_r($row);
                    // echo "<tr><td>" . $row["username"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["wins"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["losses"] . "</td></tr>\n";
                }
```

I can include additional information, but this is all I thought to be relevant.

Comment: Because `$db->query` failed.

Comment: You sure you didn't get an entire list of possible duplicate questions when you typed in the title of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, $result isn't an object. Check if the SQL query returns results and if $result should be a php object.

Comment: But in the PHP manual they use the `fetch_assoc()` function the exact same way I do. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: @Doug No, you may notice that they do error checking on the result of the query in the manual.

Comment: Exactly, you should check if $result is what you expect before doing the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

What do you using? MySQLi? If yes after $db->query() to write:

```
if(!$result)
    echo $db->error;
else
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r($row);
        // echo "<tr><td>" . $row["username"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["wins"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["losses"] . "</td></tr>\n";
    }
}
```