# Why do all my queries work except this one? And despite not working in PHP, it works fine in the terminal

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following block of code:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 1");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["username"];
}
```

This does not work however, I get this terrible fatal error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

However, if I run it in a program like Sequel Pro, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbidB.png

Also, all the other retrieval statements work in my code. Just not this one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not check for errors? There's a function for that.

Comment: I know it's returning an error, my problem is that it shouldn't be, as I highlighted above. The statement should return data.

Comment: It says `$result` is not an object, could it possibly be null?  Check for database error.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+mysqli%20Fatal%20error:%20Call%20to%20a%20member%20function%20fetch_assoc()%20on%20a%20non-object

Comment: This might sound daft, but have you actually connected to the database with your code?

Comment: Yes, as I said other retrieval statements work, so it's connecting fine.

Comment: $db is the mysqli object, yes? Try prepending the following before your query: `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}`

Comment: Or, as an alternative, before the while-loop: `printf("Error: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($db));`

Comment: If you're connected else where, it doesn't 100% mean you are connected here, hence my statement. I'd check where your connection is and make sure $db actually has a valid connection to the database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting this "called to member function fetch\_assoc() on a non-object" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009320/why-am-i-getting-this-called-to-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that error seems to suggest that $db isn't initialized, or $result is null... you're making some assumption in that loop that isn't true about what one of those variables is actually holding.

Comment: As I said, I retrieved values earlier so the $db is initialized for sure. Also, it doesn't even get into the loop.

Comment: @DougSmith It doesn't get into the loop because the loop's condition is the one returning the error. Have you checked what you were asked in your previous question about this?